# How to unlock a locked pine-script from Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

There are many community scripts available in the tradingview for free, and many of them are useful. But there are many freely available community scripts which come source code locked. So you can not learn the pine coding behind it, and the statistical reasoning behind it. If there is any way to unlock the source codes of locked yet freely available tradingview community scripts, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no other way** other than asking nicely the author to share with you the source code